# How to find out which JavaScript async call is taking a long time to complete on my web page?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-chrome, asynchronous, browser

I have my website built with Wordpress. It was working perfectly but now the syntax highlight plugin is taking a long time to load (over a minute). I'm not a client-side / javascript guy, so I have no idea on how to debug and tackle that problem. All I know is that Chrome (after my page is loaded) shows me this in the status bar:

[image]

So the browser is having trouble loading something through JavaScript. But what? Is there a way to make Chrome tell me where it is trying to connect to? I tried `Inspect` but I don't know what to do there.

Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

Comment: this would be nothing more than lucky guessing if we don't have a link to the website.

Comment: No man, there must be a way to debug that. Where the client-side is trying to connect to that it is taking a long time? Let's say you are loading 10 javascript libraries, which one is lagging?

Comment: Inside the `Chrome Developer Tools` go to the `Network` tab. Disable cache and reload your site. That's your starting point.

Comment: @kkreft Brow, that solved my problem. Thank you very much. Feel free to put an answer and I will accept it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the **Chrome Developer Tools** you can measure resource loading times.

The **Network panel** records information about each network operation on a page, including detailed timing data, HTTP request and response headers, cookies, and more.

[image: Network Panel Example]

---

**Basic usage example** for the Chrome Developer Tools Network panel:

1. Open the Developer Tools (MacOS: Alt + Cmd + I Win: F12, Ctrl + Shift + I)
2. Open the Network panel
3. Toggle Disable Cache
4. Reload the page (F5 or via Chrome Reload Button)

---

**Hint:** If the Chrome Developer Tools are open, you have additional Reload-Options once you long-press the Reload-Button. (*e.g. Hard Reload*)